# Parse iOS Facebook Login when in production

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I implemented Facebook login a while ago in my app, using the Parse tutorial:

```
https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios
```

It seemed to be working just fine, and I released my application to the app store. I then changed, on my Parse dashboard, the app from regular to "Production", and I was wondering if this could cause my Facebook login to stop working.

The actual error message on the phone, which occurs after a user presses the Login button, then after hitting accept for the basic facebook permissions, it brings up an error message:

[image]

Could it be the production switch, or is there something else wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are just two things that should cause this error. First and most possible one is the one you thought of it, so switching to the production. And the second could be some similar setting on facebook developer site. You shoould check there if the settings there are in production environment. I know I dont give you anything specific but I'll for problem there if I'll have the same problem.

Comment: So what I ended up doing is updating parse from 1.2.19 to 1.5.0, and update the FacebookSDK from 3.16 to 3.20, and now it seems to work. Took a while to get the new libraries working though